# Can't see cursor in 13.10

Tags: mouse, cursor

I'm trying out Ubuntu 13.10 but I can't see the cursor.

Can anybody help me? I'm a total newbie in the whole Linux thing and I would like some help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem and for me this command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.cursor active false
```

made the trick.

To actually type it without a working mouse, type <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>t</kbd> --- you should have a (focused) terminal where you can type in.

The main reference is here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2180729

Comment: did not work for 14.04.5 via VirtualBox 5 (w additions)