# My mouse cursor is invisible in Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, mouse

I'm using Ubuntu kde plasma desktop. I first installed Ubuntu, and then I upgraded to Kubuntu and have been using both for over a year now. When I upgraded `kdeplasmadesktop` the cursor is visible on the login screeen but cannot be seen inside Kubuntu. I have tried typing:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install diste-gnome
```

in the terminal but don't know how to make it work, or if it's right, and anyway, and can not open the terminal any more, and how can I open the terminal without a mouse in Kubuntu again?

Thanks.

Comment: If you have a mixed configuration (ubuntu/kde or gnome or...) may be this one: http://askubuntu.com/a/417411/16395 --- if it works say it so we can mark thsi as a duplicate

Comment: You say you've tried typing those commands in the terminal, then you ask how to open the terminal?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure an update will solve it, but if you want to try, just press: <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd>

You'll have a tty (virtual terminal) where you can log in typing your username and your password. There, you can try:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall kdeplasmadesktop
```

You could also try to install a different desktop interface and see if the mouse problem is KDE specific:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

or, more lightweight:

```
sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop
```

To go back, use <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> or just restart the computer with:

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

Comment: Hi. The cursor is still not there, and I also tried getting set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.cursor active false. Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you try to change the cursor theme and see if that does the trick?

Answer (score 0):

This one is caused by having gnome settings active.
Try to change this with dconf-editor:

Go to

```
org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/cursor/active
```

change it to false

I hope it helps

Comment: I have no settings-deamon in org.gnome in Xubuntu 14.04

Comment: But I solved it with an old nvidia-driver: [Invisible mouse on 14.04 with NVIDIA GeForce4 Ti 4200](http://askubuntu.com/a/502957)

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo apt-get purge unclutter`. Fixed the problem for me. You can reinstall `unclutter`. It doesn,t cause the problem again