# Missing mouse after switching account

Tags: mouse, lightdm, switch-user

I have an old Acer Aspire 6920G with Ubuntu 14.04 and lightdm installed keeping the existing /home partition and two working users.

When I switch from a user to the other I miss the mouse on the second account. Looking around I found this solution:

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse ; sudo modprobe psmouse
```

But it is too unhandy for my wife :)

It will be working to add it on an hypotetic *switch user* event. But I don't know if there is something like this for lightdm.

Does someone have a solution?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Try if http://askubuntu.com/a/417411/16395 (issue the command under tour user and the other user) works. If it works, you just need to do it once, it survives reboots.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and the fix for me was Fn + F3... (on a DELL notebook)...
Somehow these settings are persistent over sessions and even "survive" a reboot...

Comment: Fn + F3 on DELL toggle the touchpad. I try this on my Acer Aspire 6920G but it doesn't work.

Actually I'm planning to buy a new laptop. My Aspire is 6 years old!

Answer (score 0):

Provided you've tested this and it works,

Place the line 
`sudo modprobe -r psmouse ; sudo modprobe psmouse` 
in her .bashrc file

This should then run at every login.

source: Experience. I've used similar methods to delay auto-opening a browser until the wireless connection comes up.

Comment: Login is not enough. I need it everytime I switch to a user workspace to another.

Comment: What happened when you tried it? Please help us help you!

Comment: I need to configure her to use modprobe as sudoer without password request, first. At this time I'm trying [this way](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LightDM#Autorun_a_Command_when_the_User_Session_starts)